# PDFKIT - download PDF through browser instead of saving locally

Tags: python, pdf, pdfkit

Looking for some assistance in outputting my PDF to the browser once the script is called. Currently - when the script executes it saves the file called "README.pdf" into the working directory in which the script is executed.

Instead of saving the file locally - how can I get this to immediately start a download via the browser?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from markdown import markdown
import pdfkit

input_filename = 'index.html'
output_filename = 'README.pdf'

with open(input_filename, 'r') as f:
    html_text = f.read()

pdfkit.from_string(html_text, output_filename)

f = open(output_filename, 'r')
pdf = f.read()
f.close()
print "Content-Type: application/pdf\n"
print pdf
```

Ajax Request

```
                Ext.Ajax.request({
                    url: 'data.php',
                    async: true,
                    params: {
                        action: 'run-actions-pdf',
                        type: 'config',
                        account_name: me.currentRecord.data.account_name,
                        state: 0
                    },
                    success: function() {}
                });
```

Comment: Can you give us more information about the web application set up you're using? What you wrote looks like a CGI script.

Comment: I've developed a Javascript front end which has a button called "Create PDF". Once this button is clicked it triggers my script called createpdf.py.

Comment: Can you please clarify what kind of server side configuration you're using?  What is executing your script?

Comment: I've used an Ajax request to call the script. I've added the code above in the original post.

Comment: Your server is running PHP code. Any and all interaction with the browser has to happen there.

Comment: Thanks mobius - any chance you have any references/tutorial links for the php interaction with the browser?